# std::map sort by data?

Tags: c++, sorting, stdmap

Is there a way to sort std::map by the data rather than the key? Right now my code duplicates the entire map in to an array just to do this.

Comment: Guess you need another map with key/value reversed?

Comment: Have not found a good solution either. You cannot just swap the map around (as many suggest) because two values could be the same, creating a new map that could have less elements. In fact **it is impossible** to sort a map by value, as a map is sorted by key (hence why it is fast). Even if you try to create a new map that is sorted, by pushing the values in like a vector, you will still end up with a map that is sorted by key!!! The way I implemented into my code was to create sorted vectors for each of the keys and values, and used the vectors in my application. To make the vectors, I first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [STL map--> sort by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699060/stl-map-sort-by-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting std::map using value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056645/sorting-stdmap-using-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can remember, `std::map` will give you the iterator that will go through the items sorted by the key.  Only way to go through the sorted items by the value, and still use the map, is to rewrite whole collection to another map, with key and value reversed.

Comment: I found that using a single vector and simply finding stuff was better.

Comment: If you do so, you will lose the key-value pair info.

Comment: I point to Oli Charlesworth's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5056797/158371