# Sorting std::map using value

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I need to sort an `std::map` by value rather than by key. Is there an easy way to do it?

I got one solution from the follwing thread:
[std::map sort by data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992874/stdmap-sort-by-data) 
Is there a better solution?

```
map<long, double> testMap;
// some code to generate the values in the map.

sort(testMap.begin(), testMap.end());  // is there any function like this to sort the map?
```

Comment: Why do you need the map sorted that way? Are you trying to improve lookup time, or do you want to traverse it a certain way?

Comment: You can switch key with value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [STL map--> sort by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699060/stl-map-sort-by-value)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Even though correct answers have already been posted, I thought I'd add a demo of how you can do this cleanly:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
std::pair<B,A> flip_pair(const std::pair<A,B> &p)
{
    return std::pair<B,A>(p.second, p.first);
}

template<typename A, typename B>
std::multimap<B,A> flip_map(const std::map<A,B> &src)
{
    std::multimap<B,A> dst;
    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), 
                   flip_pair<A,B>);
    return dst;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::map<int, double> src;

    ...    

    std::multimap<double, int> dst = flip_map(src);
    // dst is now sorted by what used to be the value in src!
}
```

---

**Generic Associative Source (requires C++11)**

If you're using an alternate to `std::map` for the source associative container (such as `std::unordered_map`), you could code a separate overload, but in the end the action is still the same, so a generalized associative container using variadic templates can be used for *either* mapping construct:

```
// flips an associative container of A,B pairs to B,A pairs
template<typename A, typename B, template<class,class,class...> class M, class... Args>
std::multimap<B,A> flip_map(const M<A,B,Args...> &src)
{
    std::multimap<B,A> dst;
    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(),
                   std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()),
                   flip_pair<A,B>);
    return dst;
}
```

This will work for both `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`  as the source of the flip.

Comment: thanks for the sample code. it helped me to generalize the solution. now i can filp any map easily.

Comment: +1 for the clean solution.
However, it would be better if the destination map was a multimap, in order to avoid collisions with same "value" keys.

Comment: If multiple values have the same value, this solution does not work, as the reversed map can't have two pairs with the same key. For unique value in the original map, this solution works!

Comment: edited this so the result is a multimap, as suggested by theosem.

Comment: addendum added to include support for generic associative container rather than just `std::map`. Nice answer, btw, Oliver.

Answer (score 59):

I needed something similar, but the flipped map wouldn't work for me.  I just copied out my map (freq below) into a vector of pairs, then sorted the pairs however I wanted.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs;
for (auto itr = freq.begin(); itr != freq.end(); ++itr)
    pairs.push_back(*itr);

sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), [=](std::pair<int, int>& a, std::pair<int, int>& b)
{
    return a.second < b.second;
}
);
```

Comment: what does the [=] part mean

Comment: @TannerSummers It's part of the lambda  expression.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: This is a wonderful answer. The sort function can be made even more modular by passing in a Function object with the appropriate operator() overload for the desired sort logic. Nice use of the lambda logic though.

Comment: I'm using this code, it compiles fine in gcc 4.9.x, but does not compile on 4.8.x - however, specifying `const` in front of both arguments of the lambda fixes it. Could this be a gcc 4.8.x bug, or did they make gcc 4.9.x more permissive than the standard requires?

Comment: @Keiji Good question.  Lambda support was added in C++ 0x (now 11). If you add the C++ 11 flag, it should work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886591/how-do-i-enable-c11-in-gcc

Comment: Is it better to use assign to copy the map, eg: `pairs.assign(freq.begin(), freq.end());`?

Comment: My two cents: **1)** Why need `[=]`? I think there's nothing to capture, so just `[]` would suffice, wouldn't it? **2)** Instead of `push_back` using the for loop, the vector can also be initialized like this: `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs(freq.begin(), freq.end());`

Answer (score 16):

If you want to present the values in a map in sorted order, then copy the values from the map to vector and sort the vector.

Comment: +1: This (or variants thereof, such as creating an "inverse" map) is the right answer.

Comment: if i do this. then i loose the relation between the key and values. say, i have map<long, double> id2Score. it contains all the id (where id is not 0..n, it may be like 1, 5, 13 etc) and score. then if i create a vector with score and sort then i will loose the information which id is associated with which score.

Comment: @ user619237: not really. You can sort the vector. Get the max or min or whatever value that you require. Then interate through the original map and look for a match to that value in the values of the map("it->second" .)

Answer (score 9):

I like the the answer from Oli (flipping a map), but seems it has a problem: the container map does not allow two elements with the same key.

A solution is to make dst the type multimap. Another one is to dump src into a vector and sort the vector. The former requires minor modifications to Oli's answer, and the latter can be implemented using STL copy concisely

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  map<int, int> m;
  m[11] = 1;
  m[22] = 2;
  m[33] = 3;

  vector<pair<int, int> > v;
  copy(m.begin(),
       m.end(),
       back_inserter<vector<pair<int, int> > >(v));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    cout << v[i].first << " , " << v[i].second << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

To build on Oli's solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5056797/2472351) using multimaps, you can replace the two template functions he used with the following:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
multimap<B, A> flip_map(map<A,B> & src) {

    multimap<B,A> dst;

    for(map<A, B>::const_iterator it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
        dst.insert(pair<B, A>(it -> second, it -> first));

    return dst;
}
```

Here is an example program that shows all the key-value pairs being preserved after performing the flip.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <typename A, typename B>
multimap<B, A> flip_map(map<A,B> & src) {

    multimap<B,A> dst;

    for(typename map<A, B>::const_iterator it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
        dst.insert(pair<B, A>(it -> second, it -> first));

    return dst;
}

int main() {

    map<string, int> test;
    test["word"] = 1;
    test["spark"] = 15;
    test["the"] = 2;
    test["mail"] = 3;
    test["info"] = 3;
    test["sandwich"] = 15;

    cout << "Contents of original map:\n" << endl;
    for(map<string, int>::const_iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
        cout << it -> first << " " << it -> second << endl; 

    multimap<int, string> reverseTest = flip_map(test);

    cout << "\nContents of flipped map in descending order:\n" << endl;
    for(multimap<int, string>::const_reverse_iterator it = reverseTest.rbegin(); it != reverseTest.rend(); ++it)
        cout << it -> first << " " << it -> second << endl; 

    cout << endl;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Portable solution - works also with older vs's. Also smaller fingerprint in code.

Answer (score 6):

You can't sort a `std::map` this way, because a the entries in the map are sorted by the key. If you want to sort by value, you need to create a new `std::map` with swapped key and value.

```
map<long, double> testMap;
map<double, long> testMap2;

// Insert values from testMap to testMap2
// The values in testMap2 are sorted by the double value
```

Remember that the double keys need to be unique in `testMap2` or use `std::multimap`.

Comment: thanks. but i know this solution. is there any other solution except this?

Answer (score 4):

A `std::map` sorted by it's value is in essence a `std::set`. By far the easiest way is to copy all entries in the map to a set (taken and adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771453/copy-map-values-to-vector-in-stl/771463#771463))

```
template <typename M, typename S> 
void MapToSet( const  M & m, S & s )
{
    typename M::const_iterator end = m.end();
    for( typename M::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != end ; ++it )
    {
        s.insert( it->second );
    }
}
```

One caveat: if the map contains different keys with the same value, they will not be inserted into the set and be lost.

Answer (score 3):

Flipped structure might no longer be a map but rather a multimap, thus in the flip_map example above not all elements from B will necessarily appear in the resulting data structure.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be the usage of std::make_move_iterator to build a new vector (C++11 )

```
    int main(){

      std::map<std::string, int> map;
       //Populate map

      std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> v {std::make_move_iterator(begin(map)),
                                      std::make_move_iterator(end(map))};
       // Create a vector with the map parameters

       sort(begin(v), end(v),
             [](auto p1, auto p2){return p1.second > p2.second;});
       // Using sort + lambda function to return an ordered vector 
       // in respect to the int value that is now the 2nd parameter 
       // of our newly created vector v
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

U can consider using boost::bimap that might gave you a feeling that map is sorted by key and by values simultaneously (this is not what really happens, though)

Answer (score 1):

In the following sample code, I wrote an simple way to output top words in an word_map map where key is string (word) and value is unsigned int (word occurrence).

The idea is simple, find the current top word and delete it from the map. It's not optimized, but it works well when the map is not large and we only need to output the top N words, instead of sorting the whole map.

```
const int NUMBER_OF_TOP_WORDS = 300;
for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_TOP_WORDS; i++) {
  if (word_map.empty())
    break;
  // Go through the map and find the max item.
  int max_value = 0;
  string max_word = "";
  for (const auto& kv : word_map) {
    if (kv.second > max_value) {
      max_value = kv.second;
      max_word = kv.first;
    }
  }
  // Erase this entry and print.
  word_map.erase(max_word);
  cout << "Top:" << i << " Count:" << max_value << " Word:<" << max_word << ">" <<     endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to sorting a `std::map` without any additional copying or transformation is to redefine the `std::map` with different `Compare` type:

```cpp
namespace nonstd {
template <class Key,
          class T,
          class Compare = std::greater<T>,
          class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, T>>
          >
using map = std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>;
}

int main() {
  nonstd::map<char, std::size_t> const values = {
    {'A', 3}, {'B', 2}, {'C', 5}
  };

  for (auto const& value : values) {
    std::clog << value.first << " : " << value.second << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I see the following output:

`C : 5 B : 2 A : 3`

I expected that the solution would, instead, produce the following output:

`C : 5 A : 3  B : 2`

Comment: @chahu418, [The elements are sorted based on Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68846410/how-to-use-the-compare-template-parameter-of-stdmap-for-value-comparison).

Answer (score 0):

In this context, we should convert map to multimap. I think convert map to set is not good because we will lose many information in case of there is many duplicate values in the original map. Here is my solution, I defined the less than comparator that sort by value (cmp function). We can customize the cmp function as our demand.

```
std::map<int, double> testMap = { {1,9.1}, {2, 8.0}, {3, 7.0}, {4,10.5} };
auto cmp = [](const double &lhs,
              const double &rhs)->bool
{
    return lhs < rhs;
};
std::multimap<double, int, decltype(cmp)> mmap(cmp);
for (auto item : testMap)
    mmap.insert(make_pair(item.second, item.first));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the values into the vector and sort the vector on the value of each map key.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::map<std::string, int> mymap;
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair("earth", 5));
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair("moon", 33));
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair("sun", 2));

    vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myvector {mymap.begin(), mymap.end()};


    sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](std::pair<std::string, int> l, std::pair<std::string, int> r)
    {
        return l.second < r.second;
    });
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the exact same as NielWs answer above, which he answered 8 years previous to yours.

Comment: I didn't saw it at that time, you can downvote if you feel necessary.