# how to use gcc 4.4.7 to compile C++ code with the C++11 features

Tags: c++11, gcc

I am studying a algorithm code which uses some c++11 features, however my linux system only has the gcc4.4.7 and I donot have permission to update this version. I was told that by running some kind of scripts can solve this problem, that means using gcc4.4.7 can still compile the c++ code which has the c++11 features.

my problem is that currently I only have gcc4.4.7 in linux system, so I wander if there is a solution that can help me compile a algorithm code which uses the c++11 features like the keyword "nullptr","constexpr" and so on, just using gcc4.4.7.

By the way,I have already know that gcc4.7 and above can support c++11.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You where told by whom? AFAIK you need a compiler which supports c++11 to compile c++11 so this won't be possible.

Comment: gcc -std=c++0x does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable C++11 in gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886591/how-do-i-enable-c11-in-gcc)

Comment: for example, There is a piece of code that uses the "nullptr" which was introduced in c++ 11, so using the "gcc -std=c++0x" doesn't work, the "nullptr" would be recognized undeclared. @JohnB

Comment: my problem is not like the " How do I enable C++11 in gcc?". Currently, I only have gcc4.4.7, but a algorithm code I am studying uses the c++11 features like the keyword "nullptr","constexpr" and so on. So, I wonder if there is a solution that can help me compile this algorithm code only using the gcc4.4.7. Thank you !@HumamHelfawi

Comment: You can see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) which C++11 features are supported by g++4.4.7. Unfortunately, nullptr isn't one of them.

Comment: If nullptr is the only thing missing, you can provide a definition compatible with the standard.  But I think your time would be better spent convincing your sysadmin to install some newer compilers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler doesn't support a language feature, there is no magic "script" to run to alter the compiler's understanding of the code. As seen [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) some core C++11 features are not available in gcc 4.4.

So what can you do?

- **Ask** your sysadmin to give you temporary permission to install, or ask him to install it.
- You could install the latest gcc **locally** on your account. This needs less permissions than the classical install.
- Alternately, you can **install gcc from source in a local directory**. This should be 100% doable without any special permission (other than write on your home dir)
- Alternately, if the algorithm you are studying doesn't have many sources and doesn't use any library other than boost, you can **compile and run it online**. You can search for yourself, there are many C++ online compilers. http://melpon.org/wandbox/ is great because it supports multiple source files, the boost libraries and even development versions of future versions of gcc and clang.

Comment: @MingjieLi you are welcome. Which solution worked for you?

Comment: probably it is your idea of installing locally. Later, I note that our linux(redhat) system have the Redhat Developer Toolset which could provide the required environment.