# how to add -std=c++11 to make file

Tags: c++11, makefile

I want to add -std=c++11 to my makefile but I do not Where to add, here is my code:

```
hw07: test.o functions.o
    g++ test.o functions.o -o hw07
test.o: test.cpp headerfile.h
    g++ -c test.cpp
functions.o: functions.cpp  headerfile.h
    g++ -c functions.cpp
clean:
    rm *.o hw07
```

in the above code where should I add the stdc++11 code, please help me out about...

Comment: Everywhere you build a source file into an object file would be a good start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable C++11 in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886591/how-do-i-enable-c11-in-gcc)

Comment: add the flag before g++
`g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `-std=c++11` after each `g++`:

```
hw07: test.o functions.o
    g++ -std=c+++11 test.o functions.o -o hw07
test.o: test.cpp headerfile.h
    g++ -std=c+++11 -c test.cpp
functions.o: functions.cpp  headerfile.h
    g++ -std=c+++11 -c functions.cpp
clean:
    rm *.o hw07
```

Also you can use a variable:

```
CPP_FLAGS='-std=c++11'

hw07: test.o functions.o
    g++ ${CPP_FLAGS} test.o functions.o -o hw07
test.o: test.cpp headerfile.h
    g++ ${CPP_FLAGS} -c test.cpp
functions.o: functions.cpp  headerfile.h
    g++ ${CPP_FLAGS} -c functions.cpp
clean:
    rm *.o hw07
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of spelling out all of the rules and all of the commands, use *variables* and *implicit rules* to build your program:

```
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11

hw07: test.o functions.o

test.o: test.cpp headerfile.h

functions.o: functions.cpp  headerfile.h

clean:
    rm *.o hw07
```

This will have `make` build the object files using `$(CXXFLAGS)` as the options to pass to the compiler. Then `make` will build the program `hw07` using the files listed in its dependencies.

---

Other flags that are good to have when compiling the source files are `-Wall` and `-Wextra`. Those enable more warning messages from the compiler, that in almost all cases point out suspect things that could lead to problems.

Comment: thnks a lot dude it helped me out :)