# How to install C++11 compiler on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++11, ubuntu, g++, ubuntu-20.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Windows Computer and now want to install C++ 11 compiler on it. I have installed the g++ compiler but now am not able to install or upgrade it ti c++11 compiler. Can someone please tell how to do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886591/how-do-i-enable-c11-in-gcc

Comment: So just by making that file will do the work I have to include it somewhere also.

Comment: `g++` supports several C++ standards. You just need to tell it which one you want using the `-std` flag.

Comment: Every C++ compiler available on Ubuntu 20 is a C++11 compiler. At least. Both GCC and Clang support C++17 at this point.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile use `-std=c++11` flag:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

**UPD**

As per comment below:

```
-std=c++17 -pedantic
```

Comment: Better yet, `-std=c++17 -pedantic`