# Unique index in C++ map with custom sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary

I have a custom key for a `std::map` like that:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int _uid, int _priority) : unique_id(_uid), priority(_priority) {}

    bool operator<(const Foo& other) const {    
        return priority < other.priority;       
    }

    int unique_id;
    int priority;
};
```

I'm creating the map with this code:

```
std::map <Foo, int> bla;
```

And this is how I am inserting items:

```
bla.insert(std::pair<Foo, int> (Foo(1,2), 3) )
```

This works fine, and the sorting works too. But my problem is, how can I find an item only by the `unique_id`? The `find` function requires a `Foo`, and this requires a `priority`, which I don't have when I query it.

I would more like to store the priority in the value (not as the key), but I don't know how I can sort by value then. Is a `std::map` the right class/template for that?

**Edit:** I don't have the ability to use boost, also the prioritys are not unique.

Comment: You could have an external data-structure that holds pointers to `Foo`s that are in the `map`, and use the index in that data-structure as the unique id. To do it more directly, you might want to move away from `std::map` to a specialised container like [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: As a sidenote, use `std::make_pair` because `bla.insert(std::make_pair(Foo(1,2), 3))` is much easier to read and write.

Comment: I don't have the ability to use Boost, but the approach sounds like a good idea

Comment: Could you put your question to a broader context? Combining map for indexing with priority_queue might do the trick for some scenarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I find an item only by the unique_id?

the problem with this question is that the list contains `Foo` classes and ordered by priority. this makes it problematic to search for items by `unique_id`.

what i'm suggesting is to create a new `std::map`

```
std::map <int, foo> uniqueId_To_FooClass;
```

and when adding to `bla` a new item, add it to `uniqueId_To_FooClass`. that way you can find a `foo` class by `unique_id`

> I would more like to store the priority in the value (not as the key), but I don't know how I can sort by value then. Is a std::map the right class/template for that?

As far as I can remember, `std::map` will give you the iterator that will go through the items sorted by the key. Only way to go through the sorted items by the value, and still use the map, is to rewrite whole collection to another map, with key and value reversed.

you can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056645/sorting-stdmap-using-value) on Oli Charlesworth answer

Comment: That sounds like the approach I was looking for .. I'm trying it right now :)

Comment: Well, this solution will get problems when prioritys are not unique, right?

Comment: @No Idea For Name Almost: I would store iterators of the first map in the second, encapsulate it in a class and maintain both together.

Comment: @TobSpr will be problem if uniqueId is not unique, no problem should occur for priority...

Comment: @TobSpr If priorities are not unique, then your original code might not work as expected already...

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine with linear search, then you can use `std::find_if`:

```
auto it = std::find_if(bla.begin(), bla.end(), 
                       [given_id](std::pair<Foo, int> const & p)
                        {    
                            return p.first.unique_id== given_id;
                        });

if (it != bla.end() )
       //found
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @TobSpr: It is linear. :-)

Comment: Hm, I'm really bound to performance .. so I can't use a linear approach :) Otherwise I could just use a list ..

Comment: @TobSpr: Since the keys are ordered by `priority`, I don't think you can do much without using addtional data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think std::map is not the right choice (are priorities unique?). I suggest the "The Boost Multi-index Containers Library" (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Comment: I don't have the ability to use Boost

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to search `unique_id` you can have

similar to `find_if`, where you can use a custom `==` inside the `struct` `Foo`

```
   bool operator ==(const Foo& other) const {    
        return unique_id == other.unique_id;       
    }
```

And then something like this

```
int search_id =12;
Foo f ={search_id,6};
std::map <Foo, int>::iterator it=bla.begin();
for(;it!=bla.end();++it)
  if(it->first == f){
    std::cout<<"Found !";
    break;
  }
```