# Flip map using greater or less

Tags: c++

I need to flip a map (`key => value` in `value => key`). However, I want the option to sort in asc/desc order.

I think in using greater or less!

E.g.: `map<int, int, greater<int> > map`

Based on posting [Sorting std::map using value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056645/sorting-stdmap-using-value), I have the partial solution ...

```
template<typename A, typename B>
pair<B, A> flipPair(const pair<A, B> &p) {
    return pair<B,A>(p.second, p.first);
}

template<typename A, typename B>
map<B, A> flipMap(const map<A, B> &src) {
    map<B, A> dst;
    transform(src.begin(), src.end(), inserter(dst, dst.begin()), flipPair<A, B>);
    return dst;
}
```

How to add arguments to select greater or less?

I tried this but does not work!!

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename Comp = less<A> >
map<B, A, Comp> flipMap(const map<A, B> &src) {
    map<B, A, Comp> dst;
    transform(src.begin(), src.end(), inserter(dst, dst.begin()), flipPair<A, B>);
    return dst;
}
```

Erro: `error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

Comment: You could always try [Boost Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html#bimap.preface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow using custom comparator. `std::map` orders keys based on the comparator it is told to use. By default, it is `std::less`, which in turn uses `operator <` for the key type. In order to use other comparator, you can add it to the function's parameter list and specify it in the new `map`'s constructor:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename Comp = std::less<B> >
map<B, A, Comp> flipMap(const map<A, B> &src, const Comp& comp = Comp()) {
    map<B, A> dst(comp);
    transform(src.begin(), src.end(), inserter(dst, dst.begin()), flipPair<A, B>);
    return dst;
}
```

This way gives sensible default behaviour, and allows arbitrary customization via the comparator, if necessary. To obtain reverse order, use `std::greater` as a comparator:

```
std::map<B, A> flippedDesc = flipMap(original, std::greater<B>());
```

**Note:** The above code is C++11 because of default function template argument. You can still use it with C++03 as long as the `= std::less<B>` is removed, and specify function object/comparator type explicitly each time.

Comment: You are missing the comparator in the template arguments of the return value.

Comment: This solution returns the same error `error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

Comment: @Alan Valejo Yeah, C++11 enhanced function templates a little... I'll add an appropriate warning.

Comment: Besides explicitly passing the comparator? Not that I'm aware of, at least I cannot think of any at the moment, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You *almost* have it with your last code snippet, you just forgot to *use* the Compare template type you allow.

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename Compare = less<A> >
map<B, A, Compare> flipMap(const map<A, B> &src)
{
    map<B, A, Compare> dst;
    transform(src.begin(), src.end(), inserter(dst, dst.begin()), flipPair<A, B>);

    return dst;
}
```