# Unordered map how its work

Tags: c++

I have a program that counts the words in a file and writes to the file. Everything is done through the ordered map. It should be ordered to rewrite the map, and sort by the number of words (Int)
My program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    map <string, int> words;
    ifstream in;
    in.open("in.txt");
    string word;
    while (in >> word)
        words[word]++;
    ofstream out;
    out.open("out.txt");
    int count = 0;
    map <string, int>::iterator cur;
    out << "Words count:" << endl;
    for (cur = words.begin(); cur != words.end(); cur++)
    {
        out << (*cur).first << ": " << (*cur).second << endl; count += (*cur).second;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I'm sorry I can't work with the ordered map

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: @XiaotianPei I have little information on the issue. and I do not know how to work with the unordered map

Comment: Since you didn't ask a question, is your problem that the map is ordered by words, and you need output sorted by count, is *that* correct?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes i need sort by count

Comment: Make vector of ptrs to the map items, sort it using a sort fn that uses the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in `std::map` is actually `std::pair`. We store the `iterator`s pointing to pairs in a `std::vector`, and sort the iterator by providing a customized compare function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef map<string,int>::iterator Iter;
bool compare(Iter lhs, Iter rhs) {
  return lhs->second < rhs->second
      || (lhs->second == rhs->second && lhs->first < rhs->first);
}

int main()
{

  map <string, int> words;
  ifstream in;
  in.open("in.txt");
  string word;
  while (in >> word)
    words[word]++;
  ofstream out;
  out.open("out.txt");
  int count = 0;
  map <string, int>::iterator cur;
  out << "Words count:" << endl;
  vector<Iter> v;
  for (cur = words.begin(); cur != words.end(); cur++)
  {
    // out << (*cur).first << ": " << (*cur).second << endl; count += (*cur).second;
    v.push_back(cur);
  }
  sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare); 
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    out << v[i]->first << ": " << v[i]->second << endl; count += v[i]->second;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most general way to do this is to invert the pairs, push them onto a vector and use `std::sort` with a comparison function. But multiple keys can have same value. Hence, the sorted list (flipped) is actually a multimap - a map that can have multiple keys with same value.

A proposed solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5056797/2648754).