# Why does STL Set overwrite pairs with same value

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I can sort an unordered map by value in descending order using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19528891/2965184) answer.

However, using a set for the same job fails:

```
#include <set>  
#include <functional>    
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<string, int> Pair;
typedef function<bool(Pair, Pair)> Comparator;

Comparator DescendingSortComparator = [](Pair pair1, Pair pair2) {
    return pair1.second > pair2.second;
};

void SortHashTableByValueDescending(unordered_map<string, int> hashTable) {
    set<Pair, Comparator> orderedSet(hashTable.begin(), hashTable.end(), DescendingSortComparator);

    for (auto element : orderedSet)
        cout << element.first << ": " << element.second << endl;
}
```

Running with the following test:

```
void Test_SortMap()
{
    unordered_map<string, int> CountTable;
    CountTable["word"] = 1;
    CountTable["spark"] = 15;
    CountTable["the"] = 2;
    CountTable["mail"] = 3;
    CountTable["info"] = 3;
    CountTable["sandwich"] = 15;

    SortHashTableByValueDescending(CountTable);
}
```

yiels the following output:

```
spark: 15
info: 3
the: 2
word: 1
```

Can anyone please tell me why set (probably) overwrites pairs with same value? The keys for such pairs are distinct anyways.

Comment: Because it think those 2 elements is the same

Comment: Why don't you use `std::sort`?

Comment: You comparator account only values of `unordered_map` but not keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of
>   **unique** objects of type Key.

According to your *Comparator* only a **single** *std::pair* with a fixed second element can be stored in the set.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I couldn't manage to find this information. Any ideas on how to make it work using set? I know it's possible with sort, but I still want to see if this approach can be an alternative.

Comment: You can sort additionally by the *first* elements when *second* elements of compared pairs are equal.

Comment: Thanks, changing the comparison function to "return pair1.second > pair2.second || (pair1.second == pair2.second && pair1.first > pair2.first)" fixed it. Still, I don't get why this helps, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

See the [definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of `Compare` function of `std::set`.

> Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare concept, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a).

This means that equal numbers will considered `equivalent` and not copied into your `orderedSet`

Use

```
Comparator DescendingSortComparator = [](Pair pair1, Pair pair2) {
    if (pair1.second == pair2.second)
      return pair1.first > pair2.first;
    else return pair1.second > pair2.second;
};
```

if you want to keep them

Comment: Your answer is wrong, `pair1.second >= pair2.second` is not a valid comparator.

Comment: Mathematically? For equal cases it's not.. But I think that's the reason you want to override compare function: to achieve custom behaviour.

Comment: @pergy Unfortunately I tried it before and I had runtime error due to same reason as Edgar Rokyan replied.

Comment: It must be irreflixive at least.

Comment: @FeritBuyukkececi strange. i've tried it too ofc.
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/790365fb82913f9c

Comment: @pergy I'm even more confused now. Please see this: http://screencast.com/t/GzUcMZcx

Comment: @pergy Thanks a lot for the explanation of why my pairs were considered equivalent even when they're not.

Comment: @FeritBuyukkececi what about this?: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da3a5f1adb40e89b maybe "less invalid" :)

Comment: @pergy Thanks. That's actually what I did after all. You can see the comment partially behind the error message :)

Comment: Yeah, now i see that :) I've edited the answer and removed suggetion for invalid comparator

Comment: This solution is still wrong... for two equal pairs `DescendingSortComparator` returns true, but it must return false instead.

Comment: Well, it's one of the many workarounds that compiles and successfully tackles the problem. You could either use a string created from key+value and compare them or anything else. I think that's the point of customization. By the way the question is about why it happens, the proposed workaround is just addition, mathematically valid or not.

Comment: it's one of the many workarounds - it's just Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Anyway, I changed it to switch back to checking key if value if equal. That's definitely smarter