# Sort multimap elements of the same key based on a class member?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, std, stdmap

I have a class S which is stored in a `std::multimap<int, S>`:

```
class S{
    int _secondKey{0};
    int _thirdKey{0};
};
```

I would like to store elements of the same key, sorted based on the `_secondKey` class member and then `_thirdKey` member.

Is this possible to do in C++? I am using GCC 5.3

Comment: Specifically using `multimap`? No. [The elements with duplicate key will be stored in insertion order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert).

Comment: I started to write an implementation based on std::map<int, std::set<S>> but you'll need to write a custom getter and setter and iterators if you want to hide the bookkeeping like creating an empty set when you make a new key, and things like that.

Comment: In C++14 you could use a `std::multiset<std::pair<int, S>, std::less<>>`. That has nearly the interface you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to have `std::map<int,std::vector<S>>` instead of `std::multimap<int, S>` and sort as you need when insert:

```
 S newvalue = ...;
 auto &v = mymap[ newvalue._secondKey ];
 auto it = std::lower_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), newvalue, thirdKeyCmp );
 v.insert( it, newvalue );
```

or simply use `std::set<S>` with custom comparator that sorts by second and third key:

```
bool cmpS( const S &s1, const S &s2 ) {
     return std::tie( s1._secondKey, s1._thirdKey ) < std::tie( s2._secondKey, s2._thirdKey );
}

using myset = std::set<S,cmpS>;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, interesting! How would the performance compare with the multimap?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but you can create another `std::multimap` object with keys and values flipped (so that `value_type` is `key_type`) if you need the map sorted like that only for a moment for specific operations. It is well shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056645/sorting-stdmap-using-value).