# Flipping a map using transform, receiving error "type int unexpected"

Tags: c++

I have the following code, which includes flipping a map I took from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056645/sorting-stdmap-using-value?newreg=d6b84480dbd6421d927652470b0e0659). The compiler returns an error for the last line of code, saying the 'int' type is unexpected in the argument 'flip_pair<int,double>'. I'm confused about this - the type seems correct for the flip_pair function, so I feel like I must be missing something more fundamental. Thank you for any advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::pair<double,int> flip_pair(const std::pair<int, double> &p){
    return std::pair<double,int>(p.second,p.first);
}

int main(){

    std::map<int, double> s;
    s[1] = 5.5; s[2] = 3.2;

    std::multimap<double,int> dst;
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(),
        std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()),flip_pair<int, double>);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write `flip_pair` instead of `flip_pair<int, double>`:

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(),
    std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), flip_pair);
```

`flip_pair<int, double>` syntax might be used when templates are involved, but in your example they aren't.

Note, that another option (if you need `flip_pair` functionality only in a single place) is to simply use *lambda* instead:

```
std::transform(std::cbegin(s), std::cend(s), 
    std::inserter(dst, std::begin(dst)), [](const auto& e) {
        return std::make_pair(e.second, e.first);
    });
```

Comment: Of course! I should've noted that from this resource on [std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) but I missed it. Thank you!!