# Store character pointer in map in order std::map<char*, int> mymap. Storing it as character or string not an option

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::map<char*, int> mymap; 
mymap['a'] = 1; 
mymap['b'] = 2;
mymap['c'] = 3;
```

How to print 1, 2, 3 in that particular order  if order of insertion gets changed? 
I don't know the insertion order . But the order of output should be same everytime.

Comment: The question that I would like to ask you is this:  why did you choose `char *` as a key?  A simple `char` as a key would have sufficed.  Also if you mean to have a map that uses strings as keys, then `std::map<std::string, int>` is what you could have chosen.  Using pointers doesn't make a better C++ program or C++ programmer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I had the same question

Comment: As silly it sounds from the naming,`std::unordered_map<char,int>` might be the key to solve that problem.

Comment: Please show an example of your expected output

Comment: This won't even compile. A `'a'` is not a `char*`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Quite the opposite

Comment: You should make a clearer question. What defines the ordering you want? The keys? The values? Something else? Explain, in full sentences, what you want your program to do and why.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know the insertion order . But the order of output should be same everytime.

This is exactly how `std::map` works. The iterators go through the element in the strict weak ordering induced by the comparator of the map. Insertion order does not affect the order of the iteration.

> `std::map<char*, int>` How to print 1, 2, 3 in that particular order.

The problem here is that a map is ordered by the key rather than by value.

If you need to iterate over elements of a map in value-order, then it seems that you need a multi-index container. Such container can be looked up by one index, and iterated using another index. The C++ standard library does not provide such multi-index containers however.

The idea of multi-index container is quite simple. It consists of nodes just like a list or a tree does, but each node contains multiple sets of links - one for each index. A generic implementation of such container is not quite as simple as the idea is.

> ```
> mymap['a'] = 1;
> ```

You cannot use a `char` as a lookup argument to a map whose key type is `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you need:

```
std::map<char, int> mymap; 
mymap.emplace(make_pair('a', 1)); 
mymap.emplace(make_pair('c', 3)); 
mymap.emplace(make_pair('b', 2)); 

for(auto& it : mymap)
    cout<<it.second<<endl;
```

map is sorted based on the keys not the values,  If you need a variable size `char` then use `string`
if `char*` is not optional use `shared_ptr`:

```
std::map<std::shared_ptr<char>, int> mymap; 
mymap.emplace(make_shared<char>(char('a')), 1);
```

The main problem you have here is inserting a pointer as `key` means you always have unique key, for example two pointers point to different addresses in memory but the char stored in those addresses are the same which is not what you want from a `map`.
if you wanted to keep it sorted based on the values just change the key and value.

**sort map by value:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

template<typename A, typename B>
std::pair<B,A> flip_pair(const std::pair<A,B> &p)
{
    return std::pair<B,A>(p.second, p.first);
}

template<typename A, typename B>
std::multimap<B,A> flip_map(const std::map<A,B> &src)
{
    std::multimap<B,A> dst;
    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), 
                   flip_pair<A,B>);
    return dst;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::map<std::shared_ptr<char>, int> mymap; 
    std::shared_ptr<char> a;
    a.reset(new char('a'));
    std::shared_ptr<char> b;
    b.reset(new char('b'));
    std::shared_ptr<char> c;
    c.reset(new char('c'));
    mymap.emplace(make_pair(a, 1)); 
    mymap.emplace(make_pair(c, 2)); 
    mymap.emplace(make_pair(b, 3)); 

    std::multimap<int, std::shared_ptr<char>> dst = flip_map(mymap);
    // dst is now sorted by what used to be the value in src!
    for(auto& it : dst)
       cout<<it.first<<endl;
}
```

credit of sorting map by value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5056797/10933809

Comment: _"How to print 1, 2, 3 in that particular order if order of insertion gets changed?"_ Nope. There aren't any guarantees, regarding the order with `std::map`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes there is no guarantee

Comment: Storing it as character or string is not an option. I have to store it as pointer only.

Comment: @AnirbanSaha I added an edit

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ now the the order must be guaranteed

Comment: @AnirbanSaha *Storing it as character or string is not an option* -- Why?  Who is giving these restrictions?  Look at the hoops that have to be jumped through just because of this silly restriction.  Also, the danger with the solution is that you now have pointers to local variables stored in the map, and as soon as those `char` variables go out of scope, the map has now invalid entries.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie whoever wants to deal with pointers must take care of it's dangers. For now the refs are in the same scope as the char they refer to. I just don't understand why everybody want to start with pointers and omit what STL provides.

Comment: this is very, very terrible: `mymap.emplace(make_pair(&a, 1));` It also won't do what you think it will.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski he didn't clarify why he needs char* so I dumped one, that pointer is not related to the question.

Comment: He didn't, but by the way he asked question we can infere he is quite new to C / C++. And your code will lead him astray.

Comment: @oblivion I think they mean that you're supposed to use `mymap.emplace(&a, 1)`.

Comment: What i mean is that it's bad idea to teach novice programmer, that he should take pointer to local variable. In fact this is bad idea pretty much always. Yes, the code is "correct" and compiler will run it just fine. It doesn't mean it's good think to teach others.