# Sorting a std::map using lambda

Tags: sorting, c++11, stdmap

I have a map composed by a key (type string) and data (type tuple). 
I tried to sort my map using a lambda (see code below) but when I compile I got error saying

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2676   binary '-': 'const std::_Tree_unchecked_iterator>>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
>           with
>           [
>               _Kty=std::string,
>               _Ty=std::tuple
>           ]   SandBox C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm   3466
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2672   '_Sort_unchecked': no matching overloaded function found    SandBox C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm   3466

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strarr { "zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"};

    int length = strarr.size();

    std::string str = "";

    map<string, tuple<int, int>> myMap;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        myMap[strarr[i]] = make_tuple(strarr[i].length(), ++(get<1>(myMap[strarr[i]])));


    typedef std::function<bool(std::pair<string, tuple< int, int >>, std::pair<string, tuple< int, int >>)> Comparator;

    Comparator compFunctor =
        [](std::pair<string,tuple< int, int>> el1, std::pair<string, tuple< int, int >> el2)
    {
        return (get<0>(el1.second) < get<0>(el2.second));
    };

    std::sort(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), compFunctor);
}
```

So what is the error ? I am sure that it is something silly but can't figure it out by my own.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The std::map automatically sorts by key, so you cannot sort that map by value. What you need is a second map that is flipped. You then have two maps, which can be contained in a "multimap", as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5056797/5652483

Comment: Another name for multimap is a "BiMap". See an implementation at https://gist.github.com/ScottHutchinson/e63d19b60445db4e91669a198817f066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::map is a [red-black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) tree. You cannot sort it by value. If you want your map to be sorted by value, you need to flip it.

```
struct compFunctor{
bool operator()(tuple< int, int> el1, tuple< int, int > el2) const {
     return get<0>(el1) < get<0>(el2);
}
};

map< tuple<int, int>, string, compFunctor> myMap:
```

Comment: This is not gonna work. `compFunctor` can be used for comparing `pair<string,tuple< int, int>>`, but `myMap` requires something that can compare `pair<tuple< int, int>, string>`.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is that `std::sort` requires a `random access iterator` but the iterator of a std::map is a `bidirectional iterator`. You will see that `operator-()` is not defined for a `bidrectional iterators`

see type requirements [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Further to this, what you are doing seems odd. It looks like you are trying to sort a map based on the first element of its value. A map is implicitly sorted using (by default) `std::less` on the key type. If you want to sort in a different order you should use a custom comparator on the map.