# How to use the Compare template parameter of std::map for value comparison?

Tags: c++, stdmap

With this code:

```cpp
namespace nonstd {
template <class Key,
          class T,
          class Compare = std::greater<T>,
          class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, T>>
          >
using map = std::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>;
}

int main() {
  nonstd::map<char, std::size_t> const values = {
    {'A', 3}, {'B', 2}, {'C', 5}
  };

  for (auto const& value : values) {
    std::clog << value.first << " : " << value.second << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I expect:

```
C : 5
A : 3
B : 2
```

But instead I got:

```
C : 5
B : 2 // <---
A : 3
```

I checked the GNU implementation of `std::map` and I saw the `Compare` template parameter we pass, will be used as a compare function for the Key:

- https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_map.h.html#147

But it also has two functions that return the comparison object:

- https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_map.h.html#1141

Is there any way to use the `Compare` template parameter for value comparison?

Comment: the elements are sorted with respect to keys not with respect to the mapped values. This has nothing to do with your `nonstd::map`

Comment: This has got to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: why do you want to sort the mapped values? Strictly speaking thats not a `map` then. There are other containers that can sort with respect to `second` member of their elements

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, Just Curiosity, and learning.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I saw the [value_compare](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/include/c++/7.2.1/bits/stl_map.h.html#std::map::value_compare) class and thought maybe it's could be possible.

Comment: the private section of class in a library implementation isnt the best place to learn about how to use the standard containers. You can dig there to learn about implementation details, but be prepared for a endeavour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to use the Compare template parameter for value comparison?

No there isnt. A `std::map`s elements are sorted with respect to the keys only.

If you want a container of `std::pair<char,size_t>` sorted with respect to the `size_t`s you could use a `std::set< std::pair<char,size_t>>` with a custom comparator that only compares the `second` member. Though this will be very different from your map, because the set would only store elements with unique `second` (due to the custom comparator), while the map stores elements with unique keys.

If nothing else helps you can always use a `std::vector< std::pair<char,size_t>>` and sort it with `std::sort` and use `std::find_if` to check for uniqueness upon insertion.