# Why do I need to repeat the sorting subroutine when declaring a std::set?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, set

In my C++ program I am trying to sort my maps by value, rather than by key.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2699060/2675154), it seems clear that the way to do this is to create a set whose elements are pairs and which are sorted by my own less-than function.

Here is some sample code where I try to do this:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool compareCounts(const pair<string, size_t> &lhs, const pair<string, size_t> &rhs);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        map <string, size_t> counter = { {"A", 1}, {"B", 2}, {"C", 3} };
        set <pair<string, size_t>, decltype(compareCounts) *> sorted_counter;
        for (map<string, size_t>::iterator it = counter.begin(); it != counter.end(); ++it) {
                cout << "About to add: " << it->first << ":" << it->second << endl;
                auto ret = sorted_counter.insert(*it);
                if (! ret.second) {
                        cout << "ERROR adding this element!" << endl;
                } else {
                        cout << "Element added ok" << endl;
                }
                cout << "Set is of size: " << sorted_counter.size() << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}

bool compareCounts(const pair<string, size_t> &lhs, const pair<string, size_t> &rhs) {
        return lhs.second > rhs.second;
}
```

Here is the output:

> About to add: A:1
>   Element added ok
>   Set is of size: 1
>   About to add: B:2
>   Segmentation fault: 11

I noticed that things come crashing down when I go to add the second element. I found that this is happening because it is now necessary to call my sorting subroutine, `compareCounts`.

The fix was to change this line:

```
set <pair<string, size_t>, decltype(compareCounts) *> sorted_counter;
```

to this:

```
set <pair<string, size_t>, decltype(compareCounts) *> sorted_counter(compareCounts);
```

Why do I need to specify the sorting subroutine `compareCounts` twice? Doesn't the compiler already know it from my type definition?

Comment: what are you using, `map` or `set`? it's rather confusing. please give a self-contained example

Comment: I am using sets to sort maps by value.

Comment: Is this an on-demand thing or a continual pairing of both structures (which I strongly advise against)? If on-demand, have you considered simply throwing `std::ref<std::pair<std::string,int>>` into a vector and firing `std::sort()` with your own comparator ?

Comment: Sounds like standard C++ pitfalls. But why does insert invalidate the loop iterator? The iterator is over the elements of the map. Isn't that remaining unmodified?

Comment: @User7391 yes to your question in-comment. I would advise using a `const_iterator` on the map-walk regardless, but it doesn't immediately explain your fault with the code as-presented.

Comment: To answer your updated question, see Praetorians answer (which is the correct one). your decl tells it the *type* of the comparator (a bool-returning function taking two const `std::pair<>` references), but you never actually *gave* it a comparator to use. one of the many reasons I fallback to using functors in cases like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set <pair<string, size_t>, decltype(compareCounts) *> sorted_counter;
```

You never specified what comparator the `set` should actually use. Change the above line to

```
set <pair<string, size_t>, decltype(compareCounts) *> sorted_counter(compareCounts);
```

Without the comparator being specified, the `set` default constructs one (`nullptr`) and when it tries to use the comparator for inserting the second element, your code crashes.

You should just use a functor instead of a function pointer

```
struct compareCounts
{
    bool operator()(const pair<string, size_t> &lhs, 
                    const pair<string, size_t> &rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.second > rhs.second;
    }
};

set <pair<string, size_t>, compareCounts> sorted_counter;
```

Comment: Ah! And I just realized that this was my question!

Comment: @User7391 I.e. you told it the *type* of the comparator, but never actually *gave* it one.

Comment: @User7391 Note in Praetorians additional sample, by telling it the type (a functor) it can (and does) use an instance of that type for eval through `operator()`. It is also usually preferred for performance since it is *highly* likely to inline. Were I you, I would use his functor example.

Comment: I have not heard of functors before. I'll need to look into these.

Comment: @User7391 Well you have a concrete example of one right there. =P

Comment: @balki: I am not sure about that, in the general case. You can make it work with enough effort (by creating a factory function) but in general the lambda expression generates an object, not a type, so you would have to use the `decltype` trick on the type declaration: `std::set<value,decltype([](value const& l, value const& r) { return...})> s(???)`. Now the question is what to pass in `???`. If you retype the lambda expression that will generate a different unrelated (although with the exact behavior) type, so that is not an option. 5.1.2/19 states that the default constructor is deleted...

Comment: [...] now, you the workaround to make it work (just 'cos we can, not that we want!) would be a factory function `template<typename T, typename C> std::set<T,C> createSet(T cmp) { return std::set<T,C>(cmp); }` and the use would have to be through `auto` again: `auto myset = createSet<int>([](int l, int r) { return l < r; });`... put that in production code, wait until someone hits a bug and needs to read the code and start running...

Comment: @David What about `auto comp = [](...) {return ...;}; std::set<foo, decltype(comp)> s(comp);`? (I still prefer the functor version over that)

Comment: @Praetorian: lol... I was so focused on the problem of getting the type before the object that I did not see the obvious :) At any rate this allows you to create the set in the stack (or heap), but you cannot use this mechanism to create a member of a type unless you template the class and use either trick, then that cannot become a member of a larger type unless...