# How can I order a map that has duplicated values in C++?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am trying to reorder the map in a descending way depending on the values, I have been trying to create a new map and insert the one which has the biggest value first but it keeps ordering the map by the keys.

I have also tried to reorder it by the value changing the form of the map into the other way but I will loose some data because I have more than one key which has the same value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SymbolFreq.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map <char, int> mymap;
    map <char, int> realmap;

    ifstream infile{ "ToCompress.txt" };
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    


    std::map<char, int>::iterator itera;






    for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    {
        itera = mymap.find(*it);

        if (itera != mymap.end())
        {
            itera->second++;
        }
        else
        {
            mymap.insert({ *it, 1 });
        }


    }

    int max = 0;
    char provisionalChar;
    int provisionalInt;

    while (mymap.empty() == false)
    {
        for (auto it = mymap.cbegin(); it != mymap.cend(); ++it)
        {
            if (it->second > max)
            {
                max = it->second;
                provisionalChar = it->first;
                provisionalInt = it->second;
            }
            
            
            //cout << it->first << "\t" << it->second << "\n";
        }
        mymap.erase(provisionalChar);
        realmap.insert({ provisionalChar, provisionalInt });
        max = 0;
    }

    for (auto it = realmap.cbegin(); it != realmap.cend(); ++it)
    {
    
        cout << it->first << "\t" << it->second << "\n";
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: you cannot change the ordering of elements in a `std::map`, only by supplying the map with a different comparator the map can keep them in different order

Comment: When posting code to StackOverflow you should eliminate the extra / somewhat random line feeds in the code to make scrolling less necissary.

Comment: If you want to change the order of the elements you can't use `std::map`, `std::multimap`, `std::set`, or `std::multiset`. They manage the order of elements themselves. Instead, use a container that doesn't insist on things being in order. `std::vector` is the most obvious choice.

Comment: *I am trying to reorder the map* -- Cannot be done.  The order is set in stone once the `std::map` is declared.

Comment: You may want to look into boost.multiindex

Comment: Unordered_map is the one you are looking for or unordered_multimap if you are looking for repetitive keys

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly, you'd like to count how many times each `char` appears in the file and then produce a map sorted with the `char` that appeared most time first.

Here's one idea:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile{"ToCompress.txt"};

    // "mymap" is only used for counting how many times each char appears.
    std::unordered_map<char, std::uintmax_t> mymap;

    // Loop directly over the file. No vector needed:
    std::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile),
                  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), [&mymap](char ch) {
                      // No need to find first - operator[] inserts an element
                      // for the key ("ch") if it's missing.
                      ++mymap[ch];
                  });

    // Transform the unordered_map into a multimap where the count is the key
    // and in which we use a descending sort order (std::greater):
    std::multimap<std::uintmax_t, char, std::greater<std::uintmax_t>> realmap;

    std::transform(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(),
                   std::inserter(realmap, realmap.end()),
                   [](const auto& ch_co) -> std::pair<std::uintmax_t, char> {
                       // return a pair with key and value swapped
                       return {ch_co.second, ch_co.first};
                   });

    // Print the result
    for(auto& [count, ch] : realmap) {
        std::cout << count << '\t' << ch << '\n';
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
537479
120204  t
113285  e
80681

80670   i
79862   n
77984   r
77464   s
69994   o
67377   a
...
```

<sup>Apparently, `<space>`, `t`, `e` and `\n` are tne most common characters in my C++ programs (which is what I used as input)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your question may be ill-posed; take a step back and state what you are *really* trying to accomplish.

That said, I'll attempt an answer based on what you've written.

It looks like you're trying to sort an std::map by value, in which case your question is a duplicate of either [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056645/sorting-stdmap-using-value) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699060/how-can-i-sort-an-stl-map-by-value) question.

Regarding your initial attempt:

Take a look at [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699060/how-can-i-sort-an-stl-map-by-value).  Only sequence containers allow you to directly influence order.  As with priority queue you have limited control over the order of associative containers and almost zero control for unordered containers.