# Copy map to vector

Tags: dictionary, boost-lambda

I have to copy certain elements from a std::map into a vector.
It should work like in this loop:

```
typedef int First;
typedef void* Second;
std::map<First, Second> map;
// fill map
std::vector<Second> mVec;
for (std::map<First, Second>::const_iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
    if (it->first % 2 == 0) {
        mVec.push_back (it->second);
    }
}
```

Since I'd like to avoid using any functors, but use boost::lambda instead, I tried using std::copy, but can't get it right.

```
std::copy (map.begin(), map.end(), std::back_inserter(mVec)
                bind(&std::map<int, void*>::value_type::first, _1) % 2 == 0);
```

I'm new to lambda expressions, and I can't figure it out how to use them correctly.
I didn't get any useful results on Google or StackOverflow either.
[This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684475/c-how-to-copy-a-map-to-a-vector)

Answer (score 0):

What you would need in STL would be a transform_if algorithm. Then you would have to write:

```
transform_if (mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), 
     back_inserter(myvec),  
     bind(&std::map<First, Second>::value_type::second, _1) ,
     (bind(&std::map<First, Second>::value_type::first, _1) % 2) == 0 );
```

The code for transform_if is taken from [this unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278/quick-and-dirty-way-to-profile-your-code) and it is:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryFunction, class Predicate>
OutputIterator transform_if(InputIterator first, 
                            InputIterator last, 
                            OutputIterator result, 
                            UnaryFunction f, 
                            Predicate pred)
{
  for (; first != last; ++first)
  {
    if( pred(*first) )
      *result++ = f(*first);
  }
  return result; 
}
```

I think there is no other way to perform both steps (transform and conditional copy) at once using STL algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boost range adaptors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/introduction.html) to achieve that.

```
using namespace boost::adaptors;

boost::copy( map | filtered( [] (const pair<First,Second> &p)->bool {return p.first % 2 == 0;})
                 | transformed( [] (const pair<First,Second> &p) {return p.second;}),
             std::back_inserter(mVec));
```